# I forgot towel day

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## I forgot towel day

[Sandbox link](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16511/77963)

[PHP script for both examples (error, formatting the string)](https://tio.run/##pZHBT8IwGMXP9K/40ixhwASH8QSVgxqvJB48LAuprNuabGvTVqcIfzu2DAlDiAd32Lp87/feaytzuZ3OZC4BjUYeVdk7icIAMAXNS1kwKJnWNGOwpBVoQz@h5ia3wxXD8QShPTIO8IOougbmtOJLoFUCr4pXGVAwomaFfcPzI8yVyBQtSzeZv61WBdM77b1I2JMoUmc5u4OmEbLuJmcvQiUaCNT2Wysq/V1kFMZBOO436@v4yhZAuOcKpYpmJauMXlClbF8C7EMWNsC3igAOlk6M2DIXgCNCyBoPtVELxSSjxseA2/a9IV5bFYkRtlwqlO9xcj3x@PRH07@1f4NB7wt1eOqf1og8HrtRp0kE@6yhiZQ0OStvFbgJbCVXYu0KdDbACs3gxPDvLexphDboIkcucf8hWkAXd48BJ2@rz2zlcMzhuAk4IX4FHAFWvru27fYb)

[Corrected php script, the input is self explanatory](https://tio.run/##pZFBT@MwFITP9a8YWZVIIQs0iBME/sRKe6gi9DZ5SQxOYtkOXXbLb@86CVS0gDgQ5RDL872ZeTG12V7fmtpAnJ3NyVaP6WoZQxKcaoxmNOwcVYycWjhPT1grX4fLvyyzKyFekCSWNWvdQTW4752Hak3vVVuBUPIa684WDr5DXnP@AFXC1wzNbRWGUe570vppUD04UFuEW@XQtRzctMZvDm9OvWOoMRAX6M2UhJAEM@eZCnRlOF6AwgwYstSwZ4uys6Nb2be5V107hllbMvj56lIq74Y6tzeYtiFCs8D8GmOnOyIa666WWbxMjqfv8@zHRSyFXAzLKC1VDbfe3ZG1YVcp@I/RXcFRUMTYjRzEgvO6g1ylabqRp87bO8uGyUcScm98sjiVm6BKMyEDF@pEc5WeX83V9avm@DKcTk4W/8RMldFhjNVcZcPVbHJEeDaYLA0VH8oP@0EOITZDgNkzWIc/cTDw6wovtBDP4lMu/Yz7DrEHHMmjt8Ag31d/UGW35mUyGRwQ7wzeAEE@/rbt9j8)

[PHP script with more input comment/uncomment `$argv` to see different results](https://tio.run/##pVLfb9owEH5u/oqThQS0rBSqPbVZxdZMRa0AAR2aEIrcxEm8GttynDIY/dvZJWm7Aq36sMgPse77cd@ddaI35xc60eA0mxVq4gd32moAoZDyuRYM5ixNacwgoBJSS5ew4DbB4oqR2Rl89DWbPzo33cvX2uRn/xYm/V51DCPPg04Pur3B7RhuutcejK@6owZ0x0Am/eH1CK68oQdfvW@d25EH/e/Iu5wMO4PCutns9kr1J@12gyRMCAV8Dr@y1AKXOrNcxkAhYgtYKBOmYBUECQvugUdgEwaCyRgT0cBmVIhljrpPgcoQqzwFJRlGFgLuGJ6AZikDXkyFhZDpchwU2miWWkZDUBFeT4GiBmhq6JxZZiBSpnCLMhlYrmTRzMJQDeNnl4jbtJzp3tTauJFLJasWBlTyoOjuzpTJrFowkafCCQ2MitFxnld0tloJViYJVMhiJSKUf2MjQPKkPh4qfS4fqOChX8zOx7b9pcqMr0tlH@/PEfb3/28jF1@gfFaO41Qw96QYvfuSulaYT1uzRqt9WP6fzD6dNohD6mdIiQyN50xabMkYfHQusN9aYIoaIhrwIpmDHRYkCsjUdd01OU6t8Q3TjNoaAbIl364fkzWi3JlDkIfZahXunpxV@Pkz5vAz3o6O6n@cAx7VdtuYVvgsLx2UjnnkNZSWmoZvwnfzAcmbWOcNHDwCE/iadgQ/jvDEdpxH512e@x7vfxhbhCqpvibk8G30G1FextxqlwY7jD2DVwSEF2vbbP4C)

As you may know, May 25 is well known as [**Towel Day**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towel_Day), because of the many uses a towel can have.

A simple extract of the book **"The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy"** (personally I took this book as an **"everyday guide"**) states:

> *"A towel is about the most massively useful thing an interstellar hitchhiker can have. Partly it has great practical value."*

If you need more information about towels check [**this SE.scifi answer**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11719/97479)

---

### The Challenge

Hopefully you will do this with a towel used as a blanket for your legs.

Write a full program or function in any valid programming language that takes two inputs

```
size        Integer  : #The size
message     string   : #A sentence
```

#### How to draw a towel with these values?

**First using `size`**:

Draw a towel depending on the size input, [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) for our towel

```
  width = 12*size

  #the line that has the "bar" its always present with different sizes

  Width is defined as:
  from the first | to the second | has to be equal to size*12 including both ||

      <-   width-> 
  [===|          |====]  
      | 12 chars ||   1  height starts here, just after the "bar"
      | SIZE = 1 ||   2
      |          ||   3   height = 5*size
      |          ||   4
      |          ||   5  height ends here just before the first line |=======|
      |==========||   # the lines with the # 
      |==========||   # are always fixed
      """"""""""""|   # it means, every towel
       |          |   # always has this 5 rows
       """"""""""""   # no matter the size
```

**Second, give it the `message`**

You have to give it a message, *what is a towel without a beautiful message sewed in golden thread?*

**Example 1**

```
  input: size=1, message="a simple message can stay with size"

  width = 12*size

  #the line that has the "bar" it's always present with different sizes
  #no words allowed at the bar level


  [===|          |====]  
      | a simple ||   1  height starts here, just after the "bar"
      | message  ||   2
      | can stay ||   3   height = 5*size
      | with size||   4
      |          ||   5  height ends here just before the first line |=======|
      |==========||   # the lines with the # 
      |==========||   # are always fixed
      """"""""""""|   # it means, every towel
       |          |   # always has this 5 rows
       """"""""""""   # no matter the size
```

**Example 2**

```
input size=2 
message="Don't Panic and bring a towel to SE Programming Puzzles and CodeGolf"

The size is 2
That means 24 width and 10 heigth

    <-    24 chars width  ->
[===|                      |====]
    | Don't Panic and bring||   1
    | a towel to SE        ||   2
    | Programming Puzzles  ||   3
    | and CodeGolf         ||   4
    |                      ||   5
    |                      ||   6
    |                      ||   7
    |                      ||   8
    |                      ||   9
    |                      ||   10
    |======================||   #  The lines with the "#"
    |======================||   #  always present and
    """"""""""""""""""""""""|   #  adapted to 
     |                      |   #  the towel width
     """"""""""""""""""""""""   #
```

**Accepted answer criteria**

- This is **codegolf** so normal rules apply.

**Rules**

- You are guaranteed that all the input strings will fit the size, so no input like `size=1; message="This string is just tooooooooooooooooooooo long to fit the width and height of your towel"`.
- The string format is up to you, if you want to center the substrings for example.
- **Word-breaks** are disallowed.

#### Edits

I am truly sorry about any confussion, because the ansii towels i draw did not matched the parameters, added a [**PHP script for both examples**](https://tio.run/##pZHBT8IwGMXP9K/40ixhwASH8QSVgxqvJB48LAuprNuabGvTVqcIfzu2DAlDiAd32Lp87/feaytzuZ3OZC4BjUYeVdk7icIAMAXNS1kwKJnWNGOwpBVoQz@h5ia3wxXD8QShPTIO8IOougbmtOJLoFUCr4pXGVAwomaFfcPzI8yVyBQtSzeZv61WBdM77b1I2JMoUmc5u4OmEbLuJmcvQiUaCNT2Wysq/V1kFMZBOO436@v4yhZAuOcKpYpmJauMXlClbF8C7EMWNsC3igAOlk6M2DIXgCNCyBoPtVELxSSjxseA2/a9IV5bFYkRtlwqlO9xcj3x@PRH07@1f4NB7wt1eOqf1og8HrtRp0kE@6yhiZQ0OStvFbgJbCVXYu0KdDbACs3gxPDvLexphDboIkcucf8hWkAXd48BJ2@rz2zlcMzhuAk4IX4FHAFWvru27fYb) for you to check the expected outputs.

Also thank you to all the people who voted up and considered my first challenge :D.

Comment: Give me a few minutes to fix it (just saw this). What happened was that i made a program on php to draw the towel but it was much simpler than the one i presented, i had a program for the examples and  i forgot to modify it.

Comment: @Lynn added a php ungolfed solution with both test cases, sorry about any confussion.

Comment: Can we choose where the line breaks go?

Comment: The line break should be added when the `current line + next word` will exceed the limit  permited for your towel @Jakob as the php script i posted it decides.

Comment: can we take the proper text width and/or height as arguments instead of computing them?

Comment: @JohnM the height and width of your tower are defined by the `input: size (integer)` part of the challenge is to format the string so it can fit wittin that area, but as u can see [here](https://goo.gl/NPHpjw) the input string always will fot the towel size. Is part of the condition for the challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>223</s> <s>210</s> <s>209</s> 204 bytes

```python
def f(s,m):w=12*s-2;l='    |';print'[===|'+' '*w+'|====]';exec"j=(m+' ').rfind(' ',0,-~w);print l+'%*s||'%(w,m[:j]);m=m[j+1:];"*s*5;print(l+w*'='+'||\n')*2+' '*4+'"'*12*s+'|\n '+l+' '*w+'|\n    ','"'*12*s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NawIxEIbv/RVDQGbzYamLvbjk1JZehR7VQ@pmNZJkZZOSKqF/fRtX2jkMMzzPMO/5Eo@9r8ex1R10VRCOrpJc1CzM68ZKhFIZm/NgfMSNlDIjR0CWOOayyR02@lvvyUlW7gbo49AZ31ZlFE9i/pPo/RYsxxkLOeOsSsJtVqcdbZx0mxNfrHYNYYE9383K8sRQljc5bz1SVk8PlxwJsluwArYekNv/IGUtheLPGLtqIYiCYNzZanA6BHXQsFceQlQXSCYeC7xqQh8mNWpvdYx6CEUw1nYmGj/BWpDX3mOEtfJmD8q38FlSHkBB7JO2pcPHG6yH/jAo525k/XW9Wh0m96Vv9XtvO0LHXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 375 bytes

This is the worst submission you will get, but at least I tried xD half of bytes are spaces though

```javascript
(s,_,w=12*s-2,h=5*s)=>`
[===|${j=' '.repeat(w)}|====]
${[...Array(h)].map((g,i)=>_.split` `.reduce((a,b)=>((l=a.split`,`)[l.length-1]+b).length>w-1?a+','+b:a+' '+b,'').split`,`[i]).map(a=>`    |${a?(r=a.length)<w?a+' '.repeat(w-r):a:j}||    `).join`\n`+
`
    |${'='.repeat(w)}||    `.repeat(2)}
    ${y='"'.repeat(w+2)}|    
     |${j}|    
     ${y}
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFPb@MgEMXv/hQoigTUGCmR9hItjVbbqtdIPaZRmTjEwcJggVsr/z57duJku1sOoJn3e49B1PAJqYy27QofNuayVReWxLvo1WT6kIqp2KkfD4mrR50tlVKn8bFWlFAZTWugYz0/n7CtVtn4uJRS/ooR9mzHV7KBlrFKWLS@y9Q622mi0bb5KA1jINYoMOYU3EWh@dJJZ3zV7YrJKl/ze/HYF5M55FTQfD3Dk@ApKOVfvqVd8eE6wCkJLhwS5ixi9C2B/@zng/Fr6iLyGczq8@l05TWXdbBev3mdZzq7R1D17ZU38m9nys8DNz7uFR39A3MUBnJQrzH1/zXi50xfyuBTcEa6ULEtmwoyegqedmQB3pYE/Iaso/UVAdKF3jjcyeszWcRQRWiaq7L4OBycSQP7G//tJbjtiPPse/IEk4Ek27TOkMakBJUhJXiSOtiT3nY7FA8GjZc/)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>347 345 343 337 334 328</s> 326 bytes

```javascript
b=>d=>`
[===|${M=" "[X="repeat"](c=12*b-2)}|====]
${[...Array(5*b)].map((a,b)=>d[Y="split"]` `.reduce((a,b)=>((l=a[Y]`,`)[l[Z="length"]-1]+b)[Z]>c-1?a+","+b:a+" "+b)[Y]`,`[b]).map(a=>`    |${a?(r=a[Z])<c?a+" "[X](c-r):a:" "[X](c)}||    `).join`
`+`
    |${"="[X](c)}||    `[X](2)}
    ${y='"'[X](c+2)}|
     |${M}|
     ${y}
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDdioMwEIXvfQoJBZOqAQt7I53KPkDv24ZAJpq6lvhDdBdK22d3o2xvNjfJzHzn5CQ3/MGxdM0wpV1fmfkKs4ZDBQcVCAB4bh5HICERJyDODAYnImkJ2W6r0x17PT0CMtg8BOf80zm804@tZpK3OFCKiWbeS5yBjINtvFSFijtTfZfmPaXUAoqzVIliwooLEGu6evoiMs1krJm4yEOZZgXGJCGxzv0ekqW/SoSWbL0LfeDQL58XC@q85UWyfVmsuDj5zKljOebvykd/Lrxi/NY3nQpUrII/AwL/mKXyj13nm8cdIhKtQLz8wNpdZMf32SOvQM1l3429Ndz2Nb3SjNEIw7FpB2vC1owj1iZibP4F)

---

## Explanation :

```javascript
b =>                                   // lambda function taking arg 1 : size
    d =>                               // arg 2 : message
        `                              // begin string template for drawing
[===|${                                // draw first part and now open literal 
        M = ' '[X='repeat'(c=12*b-2)]  // set 3 variables, M, X , c to be used again
    }|====]                            // close and draw the next part ====]
${[...Array(5*b)]                      // open and create an array of length 5 * b =width
.map(a,b=>                             // begin map function two args : a,b
        d[Y='split']` `                // use d(message), split at whitespace, set to Y
.reduce((a,b) =>                       // reduce to single value, arg 1 : a, arg 2 : b
        ((l = a[Y]`,`)                 // declare l and then find in l
        [l[Z='length']-1]              // set Z as length
        + b)                           // add value of b
        [Z]                            // find the length 
        > c-1 ?                        // check if it's less than c - 1
        a+','+b                        // then add `${a},${b}`
        : a + ' ' + b                  // otherwise `${a} ${b}`
        )[Y]`,`                        // close and split at comma
        [b]                            // use b again
        )                              // close
        .map(a =>                      // map over that arg 1 : a
                `    |${               // four space + | and open 
        a ?                            // if a is true or a truthy value
            (r=a[Z])                   // set value of r as a's length
            < c ?                      // check if it's less than c
                a+' '[X](c-r)          // then draw a + space repeated c-r times
                : a + ' '[X](c)        // else draw a + space repeated c times
            }                          // close
            ||    `                    // add || and 4 spaces and close
        )                              // end
        .join`
`                                      // and turn to string with new line as separator 
    +                                  // add to that
    `
    |{                                 // new line , 4 spaces and | 
        '='[X](c)}                     // repeat = c times
        ||    `[X](2)}                 // and repeat that 2 times
    ${                                 // new line + 4 space
    y = '"'[X](c+2)                    // repeat " c + 2 times and set to y
    }|                                 // close and add |
    |{                                 // add | and open
        M}|                            // put M and close and add |
    {y}                                // new line , 4 spaces and variable y
`                                      // end with new line.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 79 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔×⁵θε≔×¹²θδ←Ｐ←====[↓⁺³ε×"δ↖Ｐ↑⁺³ε←Ｇ↑²←⁻δ²↓²=↓↓↓¹×"δ↖↑⁺⁴ε====]Ｆ⪪Ｓ «×⸿›⁺ⅈＬι⁻δ² ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHBS8MwFMbP7q945GIC9bCqF8WDOBnCJoE6EKaHrM26QJp0abrhxL@9vrSj0OLBHkLf916@75ck3QmXWqGb5sWUtX@ti410dM/uJ49VpXJD31QhK3obwZ5FIMf6NO4aGTaW9iDp3UJufShq7VXplPGdFAF5wG9NsMc7eWaPJgKu64peB@u@01mTD0KCce@8Kv/wXpUjiwEFt/ort6YbQ9QzylIZ3JGhhOhnjjgQkt4giONiwD39Ny4fkd4MDttey2cI3loHNCm18rR9i8TjQE4RkQBhDL4nF8NAh4FzJ4XHF2ud38PwQprc76hibHBQFiLPBsGvLxT@/jRNPJlZc@mBC6NSECaDTYgHAd4epcYVkmfgzuZOFEXo8Pp00rJqZ59sJudWb5urg/4F) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ≔×⁵θε≔×¹²θδ
```

Calculate the size of the towel.

```
←Ｐ←====[↓⁺³ε×"δ↖Ｐ↑⁺³ε←Ｇ↑²←⁻δ²↓²=↓↓↓¹×"δ↖↑⁺⁴ε====]
```

Draw the towel.

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ «
```

Loop over each word of the message.

```
×⸿›⁺ⅈＬι⁻δ² ι
```

Print each word without overflowing the width.

Comment: Marvelous, and thank you for taking your time for the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>142</s>, <s>128</s>, <s>121</s>, 119 bytes

```
:let @h=5*@a
:let @w=12*@a-2
O[===|@wá 4á=á]
:set tw=w
Vgq@hï{+@hjI    |kf|@hjjyt=pjp+@hjkl@wr=Ùjlr|Ù@w««r"YkP0xÁ|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3yontUTBIcPWVMshkQvCKbc1NALydI24/KNtbW1rpB3KDy9UMDm80Pbwwlguq2KgmpJyW6FyrrD0QoeMw@urtcUcMrI8FYCgRjo7rQbEy6ossS3IKtAGMrNzHMqLbA/PzMopqjk806H80OpDq4uUIrMDDCoON9b8/@@Sn6deolCQmJeZrJCYl6KQVJSZl66QqFCSX56aAyQVgl0VApwV1BSc3f8bAQA)

Comment: This is the kind of code i would love to say "Hey, if you do `this` you can save `n Bytes`"....but i can't...yet :D.